# Is the graph a tree in prolog

Tags: tree, prolog, graph-theory

I am learning Prolog and I have this code which should determine if the graph is a tree. The Graph is Tree if there is no cycle and edges are connected.

My question is: How can I get the solution?

For example for this graph?

Graph = [a-b, b-c, b-d, c-d] I am trying to figure out, how it works.

```
stree(Graph,Tree):-
  subset(Graph, Tree),
  tree(Tree),
  covers(Tree, Graph).

tree(Tree):-
   connected(Tree),
   not hasacycle(Tree).

connected(Graph):-
   not(node(A, Graph),node(B,Graph), 
   not path(A,B,Graph,_)).

hasacycle(Graph):-
   adjacent(Node1,Node2,Graph), 
   path(Node1,Node2,Graph,[Node1,X,Y|_]).

covers(Tree,Graph):-
  not(node(Node,Graph),
  not node(Node,Tree)).

subset([],[]).
subset([X|Set],subset):-
 subset(Set,subset).
subset([X|Set],[X|subset]):-
 subset(Set, subset).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Direct answer to your question

You asked how to check if a graph is a tree in Prolog, specifically for your example graph:

test.pl:

```
node(a,graph1).
node(b,graph1).
node(c,graph1).
node(d,graph1).

edge(a,b,graph1).
edge(b,c,graph1).
edge(b,d,graph1).
edge(c,d,graph1).

adjacent(X,Y,Graph) :-
  (edge(X,Y,Graph) ; edge(Y,X,Graph)).

travel(A,B,PathSuffix,Path,Graph) :-
  adjacent(A,B,Graph),
  Path = [B|PathSuffix].

travel(A,B,PathSuffix,Path,Graph) :-
  adjacent(A,C,Graph),
  C \== B,
  \+ member(C,PathSuffix),
  travel(C,B,[C|PathSuffix],Path,Graph).

path(A,B,Path,Graph) :-
  travel(A,B,[A],ReversedPath,Graph),
  reverse(ReversedPath,Path).

connected(Graph) :-
  not((
    node(A,Graph),
    node(B,Graph),
    not(path(A,B,_,Graph))
  )).

hascycle(Graph) :-
   node(A,Graph),
   node(B,Graph),
   adjacent(A,B,Graph), 
   path(A,B,[A,_,_|_],Graph).

tree(Graph) :-
   connected(Graph),
   not(hascycle(Graph)).
```

```
$ swipl
?- [test].
?- tree(graph1).
false.
```

The structure of the graph is encoded in the atoms `node` and `edge`.

The `path` rule is based on this [this example](https://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_15.html).

The rules `connected`, `hascycle` and `tree` correspond to the rules from your program.

Note upper-case identifiers are variables: `Graph` is a variable, whereas `graph1` is a constant.

---

### Comments on your code

There are multiple problems with the code you have given:

It does not compile with SWI Prolog 8.0.1. I had to replace the unbracketed usages of `not A` with `not(A)`. Also, I had to replace usages of the form `not(A,B)` with `not((A,B))`. If your program compiles for you, please specify which Prolog compiler/interpreter you are using.

Your code contains no definition of `path`, refer to the example linked above.

Your code contains the additional rule `stree` supposedly checking if `Tree` is a [spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree) of `Graph`, with the helper rules `cover` and `subset`.

The definition of `subset` is completely broken: It is unsatisfiable besides the `subset([],[])` base case, because the `subset` that is passed as an argument is a constant, not a variable. I suppose you instead want a `subgraph(G1,G2)` rule, that checks that every node of G1 is a node of G2 and every pair of adjacent nodes in G1 is also adjacent in G2.